# group by along with order by, not working mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to order a posts list by `id_post` and group it according if active or outdated. `status=1 when active`, `status=2 when outdated`

```
SELECT *,count(id_post) as count
FROM posts
WHERE 1

GROUP BY status
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I tried to use this mysql code, but it shows two outputs only.
What am I doing wrong??

```
id_post title status
  5        a     1
  7        b     2
  9        c     1
 17        d     2
 21        f     1
```

Expected output

```
21 f 1
9  c 1
5  a 1
17 d 2
7  b 2
```

Comment: Please put sample data and expected result.

Comment: ok. thank you. added

Comment: I don't understand what you want to order by.  Are you wanting it in order of `status` ascending and then `id_post` descending? Isn't this just as simple as `ORDER BY 3, 1 DESC`?

Comment: @MartinParkin yes you are right, this is the answer, feel free to post an answer to mark it. ty.

Comment: @joe No problem. I see an answer by FatemehNB that is same as my comment, so you may as well accept that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your data, you don't need to use `GROUP BY`. So

```
select *
from posts
order by status ASC, id_post DESC
```